# Self-Adjoint Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a function $a(x)$, consider the differential equations $y'=a(x)y$ and $y'=-a(x)y$. Let $\phi(x), \psi(x)$, respectively, be the unique solutions of these which are equal to $1$ at $x=0$. I want to show that $a(x)=0$ iff $\phi(x)=1/\psi(x)$.

If $a(x)=0$, then $\phi(x)=\psi(x)=1$, so $\phi(x)=1/\psi(x)$. I'm having a bit of trouble proving the converse. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong. Note that always
\begin{align*} (\phi\psi)'
    &= \phi'\psi + \psi\phi'\\
    &= a\phi\psi - a\phi\psi\\
    &= 0 
\end{align*}
Hence $\phi\psi$ is constant. As $(\phi\psi)(0) = \phi(0)\psi(0) = 1$, we have $\phi = \frac 1 \psi$ regardless of $a$.

Comment: Oh wow, I guess the problem I'm trying to solve wasn't stated correctly then...thanks!